# 18.04 Audio Disabled

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

In common with a number of people, I'm having issues with my laptop audio under 18.04.  When I am at the login screen I can see my audio device (internal speakers) but once I log in, there is no device visible and no audio.

I've reloaded Ubuntu, to no avail.  I have Ubuntu and 'home' on separate disk partions and have retained the original settings (and other files) in home from when I used 14.04.

Does anyone have any suggestions what might be the issue.  If I run pacmd I get 'No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.' (presumably as it doesn't see a soundcard).

I've tried a lot of suggestions from other questions oh here, but to no result.  Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: If I run pacmd I get "No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon." and if I run pulseaudio I get "Home directory not accessible: Permission denied".  Does this give anyone a clue as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after much messing around (days of it - good job I'm retired)  I managed to sort out this mess.

Firstly, I'm seriously underwhelmed by the help I received from this forum.  I've only asked 3 questions (to deal with specific problems) and have only received limited help with one of them.  Ubuntu will only remain a niche system unless that changes.  A serious number of users appear to have audio problems similar to mine and few get any answers via this forum!

Eventually, after many attempts at fixing the problem, I reloaded 16.04 (rather than 18.04) in dev/sda8 and the audio problem went away.  An issue I hadn't reported was that the partition I was using for home (dev/sda7) was formatted in ntfs and I suspected there was a fundamental permissions issue around that. I eventually came across a thread about using ntfs with Ubuntu and managed to get the system to work, though not perfectly and it seemed that all directories had acquired root permissions. Eventually, I bit the bullet, backed up my home directory (and also copied it to my Win10 partition).  I then loaded a clean version of 18.04 to dev/sda8, reformatted dev/sda7 as ext4 and then set up dev/sda7 as home and copied the new 'clean' home to it.  I then carefully selected bits of my old home from within my Win10 partition and pulled them across to dev/sda7.  That way, I was able to restore all my original files and important settings such as my Firefox bookmarks and history and my Thunderbird email accounts, addresses, saved mail, etc. Permissions for all these files now show my username, rather than root.

I suspect this answer might not directly help anyone, but might give some clues to those with similar problems.  It looks like my gut instinct of permissions problems was correct and the results seem to bear this out.  Unfortunately, this issue was spread across 3 separate problem areas - audio, hdd file systems and permissions - something I didn't realise on my initial posting,

Answer (score 0):

I had a very simmilar problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. No program could output audio, except the system settings speaker test.

I was able to fix it by **deleting the config files** in `~/.config/pulse` and then restarting pulseaudio with `pulseaudio --kill`. It should restart immediately and recreate the config files with what seems to be default settings.

After that audio worked again :)

Comment: Julian,
Many thanks for your contribution.  Unfortunately, that didn't work for me as, due to my permissions problem, pulseaudio wouldn't restart.